# how to select two columns from two tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

> I am trying to execute this query but i got error " Undefined index:
>   lname".I want to count row from one column(fname) from table a and
>   select column(lname) from other table b. so please help me.

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(fname),lname FROM a,b");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      echo "<tr><td>";
      echo $row['lname'];
      echo "</td>";
      echo "<td>";
      echo $row['COUNT(fname)'];
      echo "</td></tr>";
    }
```

Comment: how are table `a` and `b` related with each other? I think you dont need to use `COUNT` here

Comment: by the way, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an alias. Use this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(fname) AS countfname,lname FROM a,b");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr><td>";
  echo $row['lname'];
  echo "</td>";
  echo "<td>";
  echo $row['countfname'];
  echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you still get an error you can try to fetch both separately:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(fname) FROM a");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['COUNT(fname)'];
    echo "</td></tr>";

  }

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT lname FROM b");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
      echo "<tr><td>";
      echo $row['lname'];
      echo "</td></tr>";
   }
```

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand how this answer addresses the original question, which (as far as I can tell) seeks to show all lnames along with the frequency with which they appear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(a.fname) as fname,b.lname as lname FROM a,b");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr><td>";
  echo $row['lname'];
  echo "</td>";
  echo "<td>";
  echo $row['COUNT(fname)'];
  echo "</td></tr>";
}
```