# how to select two columns from two different tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to select two columns from two tables in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956089/how-to-select-two-columns-from-two-tables-in-mysql)

I am trying to execute this query but i got different output. I want
to count row from one `column(grade`) from `table grading` and select
`column(level)` from other `table info`.

```
for($i=1; $i<9; $i++)
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(grade),level FROM grading,info WHERE grade = $i");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {

    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['level'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo  $row['COUNT(grade)'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
 }
}
```

my database:

```
      level   grade          

        A       1
        B       2
        C       6
        D       3
        E       4
        F       5
        G       6
        H       8
```

My output:

```
      level   grade     
        A       8
        B       8
        C       8
        D       8
        E       8
        F       16
        G       0
        H       8
```

but its wrong i want to count how many students have grade
`1,2,3,4,5,6` but output display something else.

Comment: Ah, got it. It's because you don't use proper joining of the tables...

Comment: Your sample code doesn't contain any references to an `lname` field. Please update with the relevant source.

Comment: sorry guys, i just updated my question. so please help me out. thank you

Comment: What are the primary keys for the `grading` and `info` tables? Please post the data for each of those tables and how they are related.

Comment: You havn't provided Tables structure but assuming u have a Grade table where Stored different different type of grades and Student Grade which store Grade across each Student...

Select G.Name, Count(SG.Id) from Grade G, StudentGrade SG where G.Id = SG.GradeId group by G.Id

Answer (score 0):

I think, you must use JOIN http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)  instead of FROM table1, table2.

Comment: But i want i want count how many 1's in grade columns and how many 2's in columns like that. according that i want to assign grade.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want, but if I am correct in what I think you're looking for, try:

```
select grade, count(*) from students group by grade;
```

`GROUP BY` condenses that column into only distinct values and allows you to return via count how many rows were "grouped" into that distinct value.

More info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html